# Exponential Map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

this seems to be an easy question but I'm stuck anyway. Let $\Gamma$ be a submanifold of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. Let further $U$ be a coodinate neighborhood
of $\Gamma$ such that a point $p\in\Gamma$ is given by $\phi(x)$, $x\in U$.

Consider now a vector field on $X$ on $M$ which is normal to $\Gamma$ (locally on $U$) and consider the map
$f: U\times(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to M$ given by
$(x,t)\mapsto \exp_{\phi(x)}(t X(\phi(x)))$
How can I calculate the pullback of the metric $g$ under $f$?

I fail already when trying to compute
$\partial_if(x,t)$, the main issue being that the "footpoint" of the exponential map varies also, as $x$ varies. Thanks for any explications, comments and help.

Comment: It is not clear to me that there is a reasonably simple way to do this without actually calculating the exponential map itself.

Comment: So you think one should know the exponential map explicitly to do so? Because I don't have anything explicit. My aim is to imitate the setting, where you pick a curve $\gamma(t)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ an then you consider the surface given by $(t,s)\mapsto\gamma(t)+s\gamma''(t)$ which is embedded, provided s is small enough and $\gamma$ $C^2$. How can one do a similar construction, when the ambient space is not euclidian?

Comment: That's what I think, but I am not an expert, so don't take my word for it. However, it seems clear to me that you can't expect an answer depending only on the vector fields and maybe some derivatives on $\Gamma$. But perhaps you can find some nice asymptotic expansions valid in a neighbourhood of $\Gamma$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment... The idea with expansions sounds nice. I will think of that.